# How can I use regex to take out specific words?

Tags: java, regex

I want "is" to be deleted from a string but if the string is, say

"isotopes are related to physics and physics is fun"

I only want the word "is" to be replaced and not the "is" in isotopes.

I can use

```
.replaceAll(" is", "")
.replaceAll("is ", "")
```

but i want to accomplish this with regex for future reference.

Would .replaceAll("(is)","") work?

Thanks.

Comment: Just put spaces around it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It won't help in a sentence like `"Yes, he is."`

Comment: it would if the code is `.replaceAll(" is", "")` but i would have to write another line of code for other instances. Just a waste of code, regex would be easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "");
```

Comment: The only downside to this is the spacing issue.  I might do `"\\bis\\b ?"`, but then what about hyphenated "words"?  You know?  Removing a word is a deceptively difficult task.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan. That can be overcomed by using look-arounds.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan. Well, if the pattern is not known, then finding and replacing meaningful words is simply pain in the ass. Certainly not to be done with regex.